# Error in model.frame.default in R CARET predict

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret

I'm trying to run a random forest on the basic Kaggle Titanic dataset and
am running into the error below when running CARET's predict function.  I've tried an as.data.frame for the p1 variable but I get an error saying it can't be coerced.  How can I work around this?

```
TrainRF <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\andre\\Downloads\\titanic\\train.csv")
TrainRF <- na.omit(TrainRF)
TrainRF$Survived <- as.factor(TrainRF$Survived)
set.seed(1013)
random_model <- randomForest::randomForest(TrainRF$Survived~.,TrainRF)
p1 <- predict(random_model,train)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit) :
> 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list

Comment: Try using `random_model <- randomForest::randomForest(Survived~.,TrainRF)`

Comment: Same result. Thanks though!

Comment: Is there a dataset called `train`? Or did you meant to use TrainRF instead of `train` in the `predict` function?

Comment: I created TrainRF as a copy of the train set so I could use it in the random forest.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: why are you predicting on a function? if the fit works, you should predict on the training data or some other data.frame. ```predict(random_model,TrainRF)``` . i am voting to close this as it looks like a typo and insufficient information is to allow a reproducible example

Comment: I'm trying to tune the random forest model I've created.  How would suggest I use the predict function then?

Comment: can you edit your question.. explicitly saying what is your aim, is it to tune ? is it to predict?

Comment: As @StupidWolf points out, predict makes predictions based on data in a data frame, but you are trying to make predictions based on the train function in caret. I agree that this should really be closed as a reproducible example has not been given, and insufficient effort has been made to figure out what should be an easy to understand error message means.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble reproducing this problem. Does this code throw the same error?

```
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("titanic")
library(titanic)

data("Titanic")
TrainRF <- titanic_train %>% 
  na.omit()
TrainRF$Survived <- as.factor(TrainRF$Survived)
set.seed(1013)
random_model <- randomForest::randomForest(TrainRF$Survived~.,TrainRF)
p1 <- predict(random_model,TrainRF)
```